# lcmm - knowing which IDs are in which class

Tags: r

I am using the `LCMM` package with the function `hlme`.

I want to know which IDs are classified in each class. Some of my cases are being dropped from the model. So when I use `$pprob`, the `id` variable is basically just starting at `1` and increasing. It is not the original study ID. So I am not able to merge it with the original dataset.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is the code:

```r
q4r.fv <- hlme(i_rest~days+days2, subject = 'ninclu', ng=4, idiag=T, mixture=~days+days2, 
               data=patch, maxiter = 100, returndata = TRUE, 
               classmb=~tttantal+sexe+atchroniq+hads_anxiI+hads_depI+pcs_totI)
summary(q4r.fv)
fmq4r.fv <-q4r.fv$pprob
write.csv(fmq4r.fv,file="fmq4r.fv",row.names=F)
```

With the csv file, I obtain the following. The ninclu should be my ID but it no longer matches my original minclu variables that is a string participant ID variable

```
> print.data.frame(fmq4r.fv)
    ninclu class        prob1        prob2        prob3        prob4
1        1     2 7.416779e-09 9.635142e-01 3.630078e-02 1.850563e-04
2        2     2 5.479232e-02 8.710804e-01 7.412726e-02 9.118352e-16
3        3     1 9.933911e-01 6.607882e-03 9.830514e-07 1.110920e-23
4        4     2 2.620132e-07 9.991825e-01 8.155809e-04 1.631318e-06
5        5     2 4.382259e-04 9.877001e-01 1.186168e-02 1.166050e-11
6        6     3 4.239271e-09 2.361263e-01 7.634902e-01 3.835313e-04
```

Comment: try adding some code that demonstrates what you're trying, what's failing, and and example of what output you'd like. This makes it easier for people to help you. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure. This is my code for the model: 
q4r.fv <- hlme(i_rest~days+days2, subject = 'ninclu', ng=4, idiag=T, mixture=~days+days2, 
               data=patch, maxiter = 100, returndata = TRUE, classmb=~tttantal+sexe+atchroniq+hads_anxiI+hads_depI+pcs_totI)
summary(q4r.fv)

Then I save the probabilities and class membership as an output:

fmq4r.fv <-q4r.fv$pprob
write.csv(fmq4r.fv,file="fmq4r.fv",row.names=F)

When I open the csv file saved, I get a first column with ID that is not my original study ID but rather starts at 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

Comment: Then I have class, prob1, prob2, prob3, prob4. I want to be able to match these results to my original participants but can`t merge the files because I have no common ID variables.

Comment: > print.data.frame(fmq4r.fv)
    ninclu class        prob1        prob2        prob3        prob4
1        1     2 7.416779e-09 9.635142e-01 3.630078e-02 1.850563e-04
2        2     2 5.479232e-02 8.710804e-01 7.412726e-02 9.118352e-16
3        3     1 9.933911e-01 6.607882e-03 9.830514e-07 1.110920e-23
4        4     2 2.620132e-07 9.991825e-01 8.155809e-04 1.631318e-06
5        5     2 4.382259e-04 9.877001e-01 1.186168e-02 1.166050e-11
6        6     3 4.239271e-09 2.361263e-01 7.634902e-01 3.835313e-04

Comment: Code should go in an edit to your question, not in comments where it's unformatted and very difficult to read

Answer (score 1):

You mention that your subject ID is **a string participant ID variable**.
If you look at the source code for [lcmm](https://rdrr.io/cran/lcmm/src/R/Ordlcmm.R), you can see that lcmm requires a numeric subject:

```
if(!is.numeric(data[,subject])) stop("The argument subject must be numeric")
```

I suspect the character string participant ID is coerced to factor, and it is the default factor coding that is appearing as "subj" in the model output predictions.

Try using a numeric participant ID and see if your results make more sense.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25384901)

Comment: Was my answer not succint enough? Does this answer fullfill the criteria for answers yet? Or should I produce a mwe with data of my own?